# Find a group that the additive group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Find a group that the additive group $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to

What I understand is:

$\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z} = \{ a + \mathbb{Z} \,| \, a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and the kernel is $0+ \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$

I'm still a bit unclear on factor groups

Comment: Are you familiar with addition modulo $1$? Or with multiplication of complex numbers of modulus $1$?

Comment: yes, $n (mod 1) = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, yeah I kinda have an idea about the complex numbers whose modulus is 1

Comment: Okay; consider the set $[0,1)$ together with the operation of addition mod $1$. (For the other suggestion you’d be looking at complex numbers of the form $e^{i\theta}$ and using the fact that $e^{i\theta}\cdot e^{i\varphi}=e^{i(\theta+\varphi)}$.)

Comment: the only thing in $[0,1)$ will mod 1 that will be 0 will be $0(mod1)=0, 0 < n < 1 \implies n(mod1)=n$ hmm, I must be missing something

Comment: I’ll use $\oplus$ to denote addition mod $1$ on $[0,1)$. See if the following examples let you identify what you’re missing: $\frac12\oplus\frac14=\frac34$, $\frac12\oplus\frac12=0$, $\frac12\oplus\frac34=\frac14$.

Comment: it appears $([0,1),\oplus)$ is a group, but what's the isomorphism from $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ to $([0,1),\oplus)$ ? I know its the factor group portion that is confusing me. I don't quite get it yet

Comment: maybe going with the other suggestion. Complex numbers with modulus one. so $\phi: \mathbb{R} \to  U$, $\phi(r) = e^{2\pi r i}$ would be homomorphic and onto, so the kernel being $\mathbb{Z}$ must do something to make it 1-1 so it is isomorphic

Comment: For $\langle[0,1),\oplus\rangle$ consider $h:[0,1)\to\Bbb R/\Bbb Z:x\mapsto x+\Bbb Z$. With the complex numbers you’ll have to introduce a scaling factor to shrink $[0,2\pi)$ to $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider as it is said in comments the group $[0,1)$ with the operation $x\oplus y=x+y-[x+y]$. To prove that this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ you have to recall the first isomorphism theorem and find a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1)$ such that the $\text{ker }\phi=\mathbb{Z}$. Try $\phi(x)=x-[x]$ and then conclude that $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $[0,1)$. Can you filled the details?

Answer (score 1):

It is isomorphic it to circle group.

$\phi: \mathbb{R} \to U$

$\phi(r + \mathbb{Z}) = e^{i(2\pi r)}$, The $kernel(\phi)$ is everything that maps to 1.

it is surjective, a homomorphism and using the first isomorphism theorem

if $\phi$ is surjective then $\mathbb{R}/ker(\phi) \simeq U$ and $ker(\phi) = \mathbb{Z}$ so $\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z} \simeq U$